# SQL Return predefined string when row do not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select name, designation, salary 
from employee 
where employeeID = 123
```

If employeeID 123 doesn't exist sql should return "EmployeeID is not valid".

I tried Union and case statements but I am not getting the result needed.

Database : SQL Server

Comment: A union requires that the structure of both statements are identical. So your second query in the union should also return three columns with the same data types as the first query

Comment: SQL returns data in columns, not in strings. Your query returns three columns, one of which is numeric. You can't "shoehorn" an error string into three columns.

Comment: Do you really have to do this in SQL? Would be much easier in the presentation layer (if you have one).

Comment: Traditionally, your client should test if there is no result, then output whatever it wants. You can have the SQL test for it and use `RAISERROR` or `THROW` to explicitly produce an error message. Returning a result set with only one column and an error is *possible*, but it would usually be quite inconvenient, because the client would have to test for this or else just dump any result it gets without further interpreting it. You cannot do it in one single statement, in any case (not without making the result set inconsistent).

Comment: You can use With clause probably to get a count of employeeId=123. Whatever result With clause query holds (Weather it's 0 or greater than 0) based on that you can use another query with UNION

Comment: A query result is a query result and has to be handled as a query result. What you want is "application logic" which should be implemented in the front-end application, as @HoneyBadger stated.

Answer (score 1):

This actually has to be done at application level rather than SQL, but you can validate it using `NOT EXISTS` :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employee WHERE employeeID = 123)
   BEGIN
         PRINT 'EmployeeID is not valid' --- OR USE RETURN
         -- SELECT 'EmployeeID is not valid' --- OR SELECT statement with message
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
         SELECT name, designation, salary 
         FROM employee 
         WHERE employeeID = 123
   END
```